# Weka LinearRegression outperforms MultilayerPerceptron... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, weka

This code works ok, but not great, because it fails to account for some non-linear e.g. quadratic behavior at the extremes of the function

```
    LinearRegression finalClassifier = new LinearRegression();      
    finalClassifier.buildClassifier(adjInstances);
    double predictedValue = finalClassifier.classifyInstance(finalInstance);
```

and this code produces completely bogus results

```
    MultilayerPerceptron finalClassifier = new MultilayerPerceptron();      
    finalClassifier.buildClassifier(adjInstances);
    double predictedValue = finalClassifier.classifyInstance(finalInstance);
```

I believe a MultilayerPerceptron should always outperform LinearRegression. There are just certain function shapes a LinearRegression cannot handle (e.g. f(x) = x ^ 2) which are a piece of cake for MultilayerPerceptron neural network.

So I'm probably using the API incorrectly or there are some undocumented requirements on the acceptable inputs for a `MultilayerPerceptron`. What could it be?

My data instances consist of a combination of 20 numeric and nominal attributes, for example:

```
A01 750
A02 1
A03 1
A04  true
A05  false
A06  false
A07  false
A08  false
A09  true
A10  false
A11  true
A12  false
A13  false
A14  false
A15  true
A16  false
A17  false
A18  false
A19  Yes
A20 34
```

Answer (score 4):

The only part of your question that can be answered is

> I believe a MultilayerPerceptron should always outperform LinearRegression. There are just certain function shapes a LinearRegression cannot handle (e.g. f(x) = x ^ 2) which are a piece of cake for MultilayerPerceptron neural network.

This is simply false. Why LR can be better?

1. Your data can be well represented with linear model, in such case MLP will likely overfit, while LR will work just great. This is a very common missconception - more complex models are not "better", they are simply "required if your relationship is complex", but for simple problems - complex models **will fail**.
2. You do not fit your model well. LR is trivial to fit, actually, without regularization (Ridge regression) it is one of the simpliest possible models to fit, you actually have a **closed form solution** (OLS method) for it and **no hyperparameters**. However, for even the simpliest MLP you **do not have any training method which guarantees optimal solution** and you have to fit **multiple hyperparameters** (number of hidden untis, activation function, learning rate, momentum rate, ...). In real life you nearly **never** train neural network well, it is actually the greatest problem with NNs - they are extremely hard to be trained, and so they should never be used by inexperienced machine learners. There are numerous other regressors which can be used by someone without a deep understanding of the field, such as SVR, Ridge Regression (and its Kernelized version).

If the code provided is your actual code, then the most likely reason for your result is the second point above - you cannot simply say "build me a neural network!" and expect it to work well, it does not work this way :)